# Where does "Added By" value come from?

Tags: civicontribute, price-sets

I logged into the back end as "Joomla Administrator". I manually processed a new membership for user "Sheridan Test14". The renewal correctly shows in the membership, contribution, and activity for Sheridan Test14. However, the activity indicated added by "Gmail Test." Test GMail contact has activity that matches the activity in Sheridan Test14. Why is the transaction associated with the contact "Test Gmail" and not contact "Joomla Administrator"?

The membership form uses a price set, price field = Membership Dues financial type and price field 2 = Publications. Does it matter that a Price set is used?
Thanks, 
Kate

[image: Screenshot of activity in Test Gmail]

[[image: screenshot of activity for Sheridan Test14[1]]

Answer (score 3):

When you access Civi, you log into your CMS (Joomla in this case) with a CMS account. That CMS account "Joomla Administrator" will be linked to a Civi contact. My guess is that your "Joomla Administrator" account is linked to the "Test Gmail" Civi contact. You can check this by looking at "Test Gmail" summary page in Civi: "Contact ID / User ID" will show Civi's ID for the contact and Joomla's ID for any linked account. A Joomla ID will have a clickable link that will take you to the Joomla Account profile.